# What sort of graph to represent this business logic decision tree?

Tags: algorithm, graph, business-logic, decision-tree

How would I usually represent this business logic in a graph?

```
A is true if
 B is true or
 C is true

C is true if
 D is true and
 E is true and
 F is true

X is true if
 Y is true and
 C is not true
```

Is it a directed acyclic graph?  How do I represent the 'and'/'or' logic in the graph, in graph terminology?

(I am looking for the correct graph terminology, so I can focus my reading.)

Comment: Why isn't you tried decision trees? Looks like this is a good candidate for decision tree analysis [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree].

Comment: That is a good question.  What I didn't explain though is that this structure could have two 'roots', so is not really a tree.  Have edited my question.

Comment: Do you need a `not` predicate and is it possible to have slightly more complicated logic like `X = (Y and C) or (not C and B)`, of course, once you have the `not`, you can decompose the more complicated logic operations by introducing temporaries.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to have logic like that, and yes each value can be true or false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
     (D)  (E)  (F)
      |    |    |
       \   |   /
         [AND]
          |
(B)      (C)
 |       |
  \     /
   [OR]
    |
   (A)
```

How about a graph with some nodes representing boolean variables and others boolean operations?

This is directed acyclic graph.

NOTE: I am not sure if this is very helpful.Expecting comments. :)

Comment: So would there be three 'colors' of vertices in this graph?  Say: AND: Red, OR: Blue, boolean variable: Green.

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the [AND] and [OR] nodes and express that info in the other nodes?  It seems weird that every node (except the leaf nodes) in the graph would be connected first to an [AND] or [OR] node, and it seems weird to have fundamentally different types of nodes.  Is it?

Comment: :) +1 John I wanted it to resemble flow of mathematical reasoning. You start with some parameters(D,E,F), add few more(B) on the way and  then reach to conclusion(A) in the end.

Comment: @Nick I don't find having different types of nodes that weird though as you said its better if they all are of same time.

Comment: @Nick Miller: Sometimes, an arc through the connecting lines near the "descendant node" (so in this case, C) is used to symbolize an AND relationship. I suspect a more generalized method would be to draw an arc through, then note how many are needed to be "true" for the descendant to be "true". I don't know how common this practice is, though.

Answer (score 1):

What about using Karnaugh maps? To me they feel a natural form to represent your data..

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you might want to look at the [Specification pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) for this.

But it sounds like you are seriously overcomplicating things... you just need a composite data type.  Call it whatever you like, so long as it works.